# Pictures folder on 1 TB external hardrive corrupted and became an extentionless unreadable file

Tags: windows-7, external-hard-drive

My 1 TB external drive where I keep most of my photos has corrupted.  My Pictures folder has become an extentionless file which cannot be opened.  The other folders appear to be OK but I don't use them.

Is there anyway to convert the extentionless file back to a folder and recover the photos therein?

Comment: Since no-one said this: 1) Backup your harddisk. **only** then try to recover. 2) You do that with a raw full disk backup.   Reason: If attempted recovery fails it might mess up things more than they were before.

Answer (score 0):

You may find [PhotoRec](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec) will meet your needs.  It does an amazing job of recovering corrupted and inadvertently deleted photos/files.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion.  I downloaded PhotoRec & after some study, ran it.  After about 18 hours I had a page of icons that look like 146 icons that look like lined tear out sheets from a notepad.  They are all text files that show some form of html code except for 2 MP3 files and 1 JPEG and a report page  (sample)<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
-<dfxml xmloutputversion="1.0">-<metadata xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  I don't know what to do next.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. It can be that you hit the exhd box and the hdd(hdd = HarDDisk) take the hit and corrupted the files.
2. It can also be your computer or device made an issue while Writing the photos on the EXHD(EXHD = EXternalHadDisk)
3. It can also be that the disk has an format that your computer is not compitable to it like FAT or FAT32, if you think it is the problem you can make a backup by an expert and let him format it into an NTFS format, mabe it will work
4. It can also be that you Compressed the EXHD in the properties of it, just undo that
5. It can also be you bought an EXHD that was already broken, bring it back to the shop and let them help you

No problem

Joshua.

Answer (score -1):

Try EaseUS Data Recovery wizard. This software will add number and an extension to the missing files. Purchase the Professional version.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).